# Am not able to get activation email from docsign

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending a document via API from node server and email's are blocked by docsign as activation from docsign is required
But I am not able to receive DOCSIGN Activation to my regestered Email
Can you have steps for a paid customer in docsign.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just sending a document to a recipient for signature - there's no activation needed. I'm not sure exactly what you are doing.
Activation is needed when new accounts are created, or new users are added to the account or an email address is changed. If you are not doing one of these things - you don't need activation.

Comment: am getting error in terminal when am sending docsign 

ve sent a confirmation email to you at:\\&amp;quot;: \\&amp;quot;We&amp;#39;ve sent a confirmation email to you at:\\&amp;quot;,\\n  \\&amp;quot;Click the link in the email to activate your account.\

Comment: what are you sending exactly? I'm not clear. Can you explain exactly what are you doing